# Save files inside app folder

Tags: ios, swift3, nsfilemanager

When app save photos, it will be shown in Photos app. But I want to save photos inside app folder and other apps don't able to access it.

I get the path to save files as below:

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
```

How can I do it?

Someone told me about using secure storage. Can it be my solution?

Answer (score 2):

Save an image to the App document folder like this:

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage, name:String){
    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(name)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
}
```

There is no reason to use a secure store (unless you also want to protect data from hacking etc), as the App document folder is only accessable to your App.

Also, take a look at this blog:
https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/save-and-get-image-from-document.html

Comment: It seems it used Document Directory as I did. But I want save files in a way just my app can access them.

Comment: well, as mentioned in the link and in the post, this is how the document folder works....it is not a shared folder. The App is running in a sandboxed environment and no other App's can access its document folder.

Comment: Thanks to you Thomas and Sebastian. But Thomas, Can you explain me more? Is there any difference between my path and you mentioned? I cannot find the difference.   
Notice that the Photos app shows my images, not other apps.

Comment: I can't see how the shown code can make the image available to the Photo App. To save to the cameral roll, you would do something like this:

 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum